# Cassandra adding row vs. adding columns performance

Tags: performance, cassandra

I want to store time series log from many difference device into cassandra
I have 2 strategies:
The first one, add a column for each new event

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
device1 | 2016-4-3, "visit /"     | 2016-4-4, "exit /"     | ...
----------------------------------------------------------------
device2 | 2016-4-3, "visit /home" | 2016-4-4, "exit /home" | ...
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

the second one, add a row for each new event just like sql

```
--------------------------------
device1 | 2016-4-3 | "visit /" |
--------------------------------
device1 | 2016-4-4 | "exit /"  |
--------------------------------
....    | ...      | ....
```

which one will give more inserting performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a confusion over how Cassandra works. In Cassandra we think about data modeling as "partitions" and "rows".

A partition contains many logical groupings of columns we call a "row". The ordering of rows within a `Partition` is based on a `Clustering Key` which is a set of columns in that row.

In IOT use cases this typically plays out as a `Partition` representing a single device. Then the rows within the partition representing events emitted by that device. The `Clustering Key` is set to the emission time (more often a `TIMEUUID` for the event. This builds up partitions that look like

```
DeviceID -> [TimeUUID_1, (DataA, DataB, DataC) ], [TimeUUID_2, (DataA, DataB, DataC) ] ...
```

This partition would have been described by a schema like

```
CREATE TABLE timeseries (
  DeviceID UUID, 
  EventTime TIMEUUID, 
  DataA Text, 
  DataB Text, 
  DataC Text, 
  PRIMARY KEY (DeviceID, EventTIme)
)
```

For more examples see [time series data-modeling](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling)

Which details a few different styles of modeling time series data based on these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to model on a non-existent problem. You should only model based on your queries.

A typical (reverse) time-series model is:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
    device int, 
    ts ts, 
    event text,
    PRIMARY KEY (device , ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts DESC);
```

where you can easily (and efficiently) retrieve all the events for a particular device with

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE device = ?;
```

and you can further restrict your results to a specific time window with

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE device = ? AND ts >= ? AND ts <= ?;
```